# Relative Path (pathlib) name working on MAC OS but on Windows gives me a error

Tags: operating-system, relative-path, pathlib

Currently I am working a project that has have been using the `pathlib` library so I can work on my Windows desktop when I need too and on my MacBook Pro. Essentially be able to work between both operating systems. I have not have any issues at all until right now. Here is the set up:

I have a pipeline set up to automatically save a `.joblib` and a whole lot of `.png` files that will go to a directory called

`output_dir = Path('../Trained_Models/Differential_gene_analysis/A Kidney Cancer Transcriptome Molecular Signature Identifies Tumors with Tumor Thrombus/Models train on TCGA data and test on Rodriguez data/Oct-XX-20XX')`

For example, if I want to save a `.joblib` file under the name `RandomForest_TumorThrombus_104.joblib`,I would use the command

`joblib.dump(model ,output_dir / 'RandomForest_TumorThrombus_104.joblib')`

On my MacBook Pro, I have no issues when this is ran, but on Windows it gives me the following error

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\Trained_Models\\Differential_gene_analysis\\A Kidney Cancer Transcriptome Molecular Signature Identifies Tumors with Tumor Thrombus\\Models train on TCGA data and test on Rodriguez data\\Oct-17-2022\\RandomForest_TumorThrombus_104.joblib'`

I have tried to use the `.resolve()` method to get the absolute path but still gives me the same error. I have tried to experiment to try to see what is goin on such as using `os.path.exists()`. When using the `os.path.exists()` method I get `True` for the follwoing command:

`os.path.exists(output_dir)`

So it does indeed recognize that the directory exists. The next thing I tried was to rename the file to something like `dddddd.joblib` and that worked. But I find that only a few names for the file would allow me to save the files. During debug I found that the most recent Traceback occurs here:

````
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:```


I was wondering if anyone here had any idea what was going on here and how I can fix this issue? Please and Thank you.
````

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable long paths on Windows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).